# Table-valued parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting error while passing TVP to a stored procedure

My code is

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection();
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("SPName",con);

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("vpTableGuid");

dataTable.Columns.Add("id1", typeof(Guid));
dataTable.Columns.Add("rowNum", typeof(Int32));

dataTable.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid(),1);
dataTable.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid(),2);
dataTable.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid(),3);

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@evaluatorList", dataTable);                        
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
param.TypeName = "dbo.vpTableGuid";

command.Parameters.Add(param);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The above code throws an error:

> *INSERT into an identity column not allowed on table variables.*
>   *The data for table-valued parameter "@evaluatorList" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter.*

Comment: Can you show us the definition of your stored procedure, too? Obviously there's a discrepancy between what the stored procedure expects and how you're calling it from C# ....

Comment: Looks like you are trying to insert value in the column that is an identity. What type of column is your "id1" ?

Comment: It would help if you could show the definition for `vpTableGuid` too.

Comment: can you provide your table definition ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the identity column manually in SQL.

Define your primary key column in SQL as such:

```
id1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY
```

Remove this line of code:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("id1", typeof(Guid));
```

And change your vpTableGuid definition to not include the id1 column.

Comment: It's complaining about an `IDENTITY` column. Since, by definition, that can't be a `uniqueidentifier` column, it can't be complaining about `id1`.

Comment: Ah good catch.  That was silly.  I guess we need to see his TVP definition and maybe the stored proc as well.